# How to select multiple cell from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 2, 1:3, 2: 5},'b': {0: 5, 1:3, 2:6}, 'c': {0: 2, 1:1, 2:2}})
a
OUT:
    a   b   c
0   2   5   2
1   7   3   1
2   5   6   2
```

and i have the following positions:

```
index_coords = [0, 1]
columns_coords = ['b', 'b']
```

I would like to get:

```
b  0    5
b  1    3
```

I used the following:

```
a.unstack(-1).loc[[(col, row) for col, row in zip(columns_coords, index_coords)]]
b  0    5
b  1    3
```

I'm interested in a more straight forward method, something like(if exists):

```
a.get_by_coords(index_coords, columns_coords)
```

I want to find out if there exists any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not exist in npandas, your solution is nice. Also should be simplier:

```
print (a.unstack(-1).loc[list(zip(columns_coords, index_coords))])
b  0    5
   1    3
dtype: int64
```

Close what you need is select by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
#swapped columns, index lists
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([columns_coords,index_coords])
print (a.unstack(-1).loc[mux])
b  0    5
   1    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` with `reindex` + `swaplevel`:

```
a.stack().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([index_coords,columns_coords])).swaplevel(i=0,j=1)
b  0    5
   1    3
dtype: int64
```